# Magento 2.3.6 Add Custom Sort For Product Graphql

Tags: magento2.3

I want to sort the products graphql with backorder and is_in_stock attribute. Please let me know if anyone has any solution for it.
I tried with quantity_and_stock_status it is applied only on qty.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any special query methods to retrieve custom attributes. We can just pass the custom attribute code to the query. And also for filtering you can simply pass the attribute name, please follow this documentation:

CHeck this  -> [GraphQL Custom Filters](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/graphql/custom-filters.html)